# Как изменять некоторые поля в json отображении с Play Framework 2?

Tags: scala, playframework

У меня есть такой класс:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class EmailRequest (apiKey: String, username: String)

object EmailRequest {
  implicit val emailRequestWrites = Json.writes[EmailRequest]
}
```

Он прекрасно преобразовывается в json. Есть только проблема с поле apiKey. Клиент ожидает получить api_key, а у меня это apiKey.

Можно как-нибудь сделать в объекте-спутнике так, чтобы он подменял название только одного поля?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Json.writes` реализован с помощью макросов, т.е. вот это:

```
implicit val emailRequestWrites = Json.writes[EmailRequest]
```

во время компиляции само переписывается на это:

```
implicit val emailRequestWrites: Writes[EmailRequest] = (
  (JsPath \ "apiKey").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "username").write[String]
  )(unlift(EmailRequest.unapply))
```

Т.е. если нужен кастомный конвертер, то можно и прямо самому написать то, что выше. Лишь заменив ключи на нужные.

На всякий случай вот импорты:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, Writes}
```

Вот [дока](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#writes) по кастомным JSON конвертерам.